# Error with variable declaration in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know, TypeScript generate JavaScript file with equivalent code.

But, here is a problem, where **TypeScript doesn't generate equivalent JavaScript code**.

**demo.ts**

```
function foo()
{
    if(1)
    {
        let myName = "Raktim";
    }
    console.log(myName);
}
foo();
```

**demo.js**

```
function foo() {
    if (1) {
        var myName = "Raktim";
    }
    console.log(myName);
}
foo();
```

See above, I declared a locale variable **myName** in the **demo.ts** file. But, look the JavaScript code it declare **myName** variable as global variable.

Summary: TypeScript generated JavaScript code's variable always are in global scope (in my case).

So, end of the code the meaning is changed. Why?

Comment: Did you intend your code to result in a reference error? If your run your TS code (which is also valid JS code) as JS, you'll get a reference error because `let` causes `myName` to be scoped to the `if`, so the `console.log` won't be able to use it. The JS you shared wouldn't have that problem because `myName` would be hoisted into `foo`'s scope (not the global scope).

Comment: @TheJim01...Yes, I expect it should give reference error as a result. Because, I declare **locale** variable in TS code but it act as global variable in JS code. So, obviously browser treat it as a global variable. Which I didn't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using something like webpack that use babel to transpile code.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env

you need to tell babel your target browser.

ex if you target the last chrome that read let and const the compiled code doesn't change

UPDATE:
solved in comment
using --target options
ex: tsc --target ES2016 file.ts

Comment: Hey, Sandro I'm surrender to you. I don't know what is babel or how to tell about my target browser to babel! Can you tell me more about this?

Comment: can you tell me what start code have you use? because there are several way to setup, if your project is new, i think you can configure the browser target in your package.json

"browserslist": ['last 1 Chrome versions']

Comment: I just create **demo.ts** file with Sublime Text 3. Where are **package.json** file?

Comment: you can see also how babel transpile code here https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=last%201%20Chrome%20versions&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAUAby4gxGYNARm0MT0soBsBTKRAWwE8A5AQ2fsQF5EAIgBKnANaxmggNz5CAXzkEICAM5wGAOlpwA5mjZceGWYpToTQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Ctypescript%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.2&externalPlugins=

Comment: mmm... which command do you use for generate js from ts files?

Comment: I used **tsc demo.ts** command to compile TS code. Yes, I will read the article. But, how to disable **babel**. I didn't install it, but how it was installed automatically?

Comment: also typescript can transpile code, can you please try to run **tsc --lib ES6 demo.ts**?
or **tsc --lib ES2016 demo.ts**

Comment: Yes, I tried **tsc --lib ES6 demo.ts** after seeing your comment. But nothing changed in the JavaScript code.

Comment: do you try also **tsc --lib ES2016 demo.ts**?

Comment: Yes, after your comment I also tried **tsc --lib ES2016 demo.ts**, but result does not changed!

Comment: can you give me another try? :) 
try this **tsc --target ES2016 demo.ts**

Comment: Yes, man thanks a lot. You solved my issue! I'm glad. I'm Interested to know how to disable **babel** or uninstalled it. Can you guide me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215956/discussion-between-raktim-banerjee-and-sandro-gianola).